# What program could I use on debian to countdown the time?

Tags: gnome, timer

I'm trying out the http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/ technique and I'm looking for a GUI clock applet to keep track of the time.

I've tried `timer-applet` found by `apt-cache search gnome timer` but I'm looking for something more visually appealing - can anyone recommend a program?

Comment: You should take your pomodoro break from finding a timer in gnome :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kteatime (from KDE, but should work under Gnome) is quite nice: http://runme.org/project/+kteatime/

But timer-applet also looks nice, so I'm not sure what you mean by "visually appealing". Could you explain?

If you want something simple but nice, you could also just write a shell script that plays a melody (random, if you want) every 25 minutes, or pops up a nice image...